# How to commit edit or end edit on selection confirmed for datagridview combobox cell?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

**Problem:** I want to commit an edit for when the user has a datagridview combobox cell, i.e. it would be the regular combo box cell's "Selection Committed"

**What I've Tried:** So based off a lot of stackflow questions (like [Datagridview comboBox not selecting on click/edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23245421/datagridview-combobox-not-selecting-on-click-edit/23361088#23361088) ) where they look at the event called such as selected index changed, the cell value changed, cell content click, and edit control showing. 
  In these event handlers I have tried to commit the edit, but it instead calls this event **after** another cell has clicked, not once the selected item has been chosen in the cell. I've already tried making a "selected index changed" handler and definition, but since the combobox cell doesn't have that event, I get an error in vb.net

Here's a sample code snippet:

```
 Private Sub editingComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    editCameraTable.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    editCameraTable.EndEdit()
End Sub
```

This isn't called until another cell is clicked or otherwise. Any suggestions on how to flag this event for a datagridviewcomboboxcell?

Answer (score 0):

Handel the CellEndEdit action. Yes it only fires after the person clicks elsewhere; but combine it with a keydown preview..  People naturally click return at the end of a text edit and you can use this to trigger the update. A Cell in a gridview can't determine when a person is done typing in it, so it needs the person to click out of it before the edit commit occurs. The only other way around this is perhaps using a timer that resets on each keydown event and updates if the typing goes idle.

```
Private Sub datagridview1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, _
               ByVal e As System.EventArgs) HAndels datagridview1.CellEndEdit

   '  If InLoad = True Then Exit Sub ' may want to suppress if you are programmatically changing this

   datagridview1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange)
   ' Do your saves... 


End Sub

Private Sub datagridview1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) _
     Handles datagridview1.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Return Then
        datagridview1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this. However, when I click the drop down for the datagridviewcomboboxcell, while still highlighted, and pressed enter, all it did was change the cell. KeyDown never was called.